# Where can I find VMware tools 8.7.0?

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I have a VM installed using VMware Workstation 7.1.4 build-385536 running ubuntu 11.10.

I'm trying to install VMware player on this ubuntu VM:

```
gksudo bash VMware-Player-4.0.1-528992.x86_64.bundle
```

but I get an error telling me to install version 8.7.0 of VMware tools:

My question is where can I find VMware tools 8.7.0?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

VMWare Workstation (by default) automaticall installs VMWare tools. Since you're running older version of VMWare Workstation, your VMWare tools version is also outdated.

However, now you're trying to install newer version of VMWare player which requires newer version of VMWare tools.

Therefore, it is obvious that you get the above mention error. Also note that you **cannot** run two different version of VMWare tools simultaneously.

**SOLUTION**

**Best Choice :** Uninstall older version of VMWare Workstation and install new version of VMWare Workstation (version 8.x.x. build-xxxxx) along with VMWare tools. [here is the link](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/wkst_801_lx/dCVkYnRwdHBidGRoag==)

**(Just a) choice :** Remove new version of VMWare player (version 4.x.x) and install older version of VMWare player that matches to your existing VMWare Workstation version. (Here I assume you have installed your existing VMWare Workstation along with VMWare tools.)

Hope these information will guide you :)

Answer (score 1):

http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.0latest/ubuntu/dists/index.html

here you can find a repository from VMware, the official website also provides support and other resources but you have to register yourself in their database.

you can find a complete guide about how to install the vmware tools on your machine here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools

Depending on the version of Ubuntu installed you can probably choose between the open-source-vmware-tools and the closed-source-verion , the guide linked above describes the two types of installation.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools

will install VMware Tools 8.9 (build 450511) as of this writing.